# Не работают точки останова в связке PHP Storm + Xdebug + Open Server. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver, xdebug, пути

уважаемые коллеги! Пользуюсь PHP Storm, пытаюсь настроить дебаггер, но не могу добиться, чтобы срабатывали точки останова. Открываю скрипт pars.php, запускаю его в дебаггере нажатием на зеленый треугольник:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня там проставлено несколько точек останова, но в IDE потушена стрелка, с помощью которой, насколько я понимаю, могу по ним передвигаться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересно, что в браузере подставляется неверный путь:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

на самом деле, localhost и parser -два отдельных домена локального сервера. parserlic находится не внутри localhost. В IDE и в файле конфигурации сервера прописал правильно и порты и пути... Может быть, у кого-то была сходная проблема?

Comment: потому что неправильно сервер настроил в phpstorm (пути к файлам или веб-адрес), я включаю телефонную трубку и просто запускаю в браузере скрипт, без зеленого треугольника.

Comment: Не нужно запускать файл в IDE (только консольный нужно так запускать). Настройте [локальный домен](https://php-start.com/blog/open-server-domains-php-start-project) в OpenServer на директорию где находится ваш файл, и добавляйте к нему имя вашего файла. [Для отладки](https://knasys.ru/организация-локальной-разработки-на-word/) добавьте передачу параметра типа PHPSTORM из браузера при помощи расширения.

Comment: кстати да, для firefox юзаю расширение Xdebug helper